# Responding to a form submission with js, getting: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the controller code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if user
    format.js { render js: 'enter_your_password()' }
  else
    format.js { render js: 'check_your_email()' }
  end
end
```

When I call it by submitting a form, I get this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an ajax request, the **form** or **button** must be `remote: true` or `local: false`.